# Regex to Match White Space or End of String

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to find every instance of @username in comment text and replace it with a link. Here's my PHP so far:

```
$comment = preg_replace('/@(.+?)\s/', '<a href="/users/${1}/">@${1}</a> ', $comment);
```

The only problem is the regex is dependent upon there being whitespace after the @username reference. Can anyone help me tweak this so it will also match if it is at the end of the string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try `/@(\w+)/` instead of `/@(.+?)\s/`.

Comment: Excellent - that worked perfectly! Can you tell me more about \w?

Comment: @Kirk: \w simply matches any 'word' character: A-Za-z0-9_

Answer (score 14):

To detect whitespace or end of string, you would use: `/@(.+?)(?=\s|$)/`, but unless your usernames contain non-alphanumeric characters, it's simpler to use the `\w` for word character or `\b` for word break, i.e.: `/@(.+?)\b/` or  `/@(\w)+/`.

Comment: Or could we use that to determine whether to add a white-space at the end of the link? `$comment = preg_replace('/@(.+?)(?:\s|$)/', '<a href="/users/${1}/">@${1}</a>${2}', $comment);`

Comment: Yes, but in that case you'll have to use a capturing group (remove the `?:`).

Comment: This actually was really helpful! Thanks for the white space fix

Comment: `(?=\s|$)` a big big help for the regexly-challenged people! Thank you for that trick.