# With python, what is the most efficient means to collect the text between 2 symbols in a string?

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex to Match White Space or End of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490478/regex-to-match-white-space-or-end-of-string)

So if a user submits a text box containing the @ symbol (@username), how can I efficiently grab the username between the @ and the next space?

Also, there may be multiple @users in one submission so would like each appended to a list, but only if it was not already in the list.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "between the @ and the next space"?  What do you want `@person1,@person2,@person3` to return?

Comment: What did you try that's not working?

Comment: Your question is tagged `[regex]`, can you post the ones you tried?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm not sure, but I think he wants to know what python function to use.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @DSM that would output ['person1', 'person2', 'person3']

Comment: @chrickso: then you don't mean "next space", do you?  That string doesn't have any spaces at all, and that fact will break some of the non-regex solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing it for a lot of text, regex is easiest:

```
import re
mystring = " Hello there @ben, my name is @bob"
re.findall(r'@(\w+)', mystring)

// ['ben', 'bob']
```

Answer (score 1):

without `regex` solution:

```
>>> strs="@user some text @user2"
>>> [x.split()[0] for x in strs.split('@')[1:] if x.strip()!='']
['user', 'user2']

>>> strs1="hello I am @user1 and he's @user2"
>>> [x.split()[0] for x in strs1.split('@')[1:] if x.strip()!='']
['user1', 'user2']
```

**edit:**

```
lis=[]
strs="hello I am @user1 and he's @user2,  as per @user3, @user2 is older than @user1"
for x in strs.split('@')[1:]:
    x=x.split()[0].strip().strip(',";.')   #strip punctuation marks
    if x not in lis:        #if not in lis
        lis.append(x)

print lis
```

**output:**

```
['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
```

Comment: What about not adding to the list if it already exists? If doing this to a large amount of text, is it faster to edged or non-regex?

Comment: @chrickso I've edited my answer as per your comment. But if you want to use list comprehensions only then you can use `set()` to remove repeated names.

Comment: @chrickso, when evaluating code speed the only reliable way is to benchmark it yourself. You now have at least two possible solutions so it should be easy for you to try.

Comment: @mark any pointers on where to learn how to do code processing time benchmarks?

Comment: @chrickso check out the [timeit module](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html).

Comment: ashwini, thanks but per @DSM comments above, it would make sense to have this break at any non-alphanumeric, not just spaces. Usernames will only be letters/numbers so anything between @ and the next non-letter/number needs in the list

Answer (score 0):

Efficient in terms of what?  Coding time?  try a regex:

```
import re
re.findall(r'@([^\s]*)',"this is @astring with @another one")
```

Comment: Efficient as in drag on the computer for frequently repeating on large amount of text